# Transform duration not working in firefox

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, svg, jsx

I have used transform translate and scale on SVG g tag and provided transition-duration:1s. It is working fine in Chrome.

Problem is that  duration effect not working in FireFox.

```
let mapStyle = {
    transitionDuration: "700ms",
    transformOrigin: "center"
};
return(
    <g className="map" style={mapStyle} ref={(n) => this.topologyGroup = n}>
        <RingGroup fabrics={fabrics}/>
    </g>
);

<g class="map" style="transition-duration: 700ms; transform-origin: center center 0px;"> </g>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this I think its useful for you It is a problem with **transform** value, in **Firefox** transform is prefixed with **-moz-transform**. you should have to use like this below the prefix property with **transform-duration: 700ms;** property.

```
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
```

Comment: Tried prefix as you suggested but getting same issue.
Here is the css:-
.map {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 700ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 700ms;
    -ms-transition-duration: 700ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 700ms;
    transition-duration: 700ms;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
}

please correct if i am wrong.